# JSON decode in php web programming

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl, response

I am facing a problem in php using CURL. I made a https request and I got response in multidimesional array.

```
[{  
 "id":"22622",
 "name":"",
 "email":"ffv7678@gmail.com",
 "mobileno":"",
 "birth_dt":"",
 "marital_status":"",
 "gender":"",
 "educationid":"0",
 "occupationid":"0",
 "industryid":"0",
 "incomeid":"",
 "city":"0",
 "state":"0",
 "country":"0",
 "postcode":"",
 "deviceid":"805086099499488",
 "regid":"",
 "device_type":null,
 "userstatus":"0",
 "refcode":"D1219C92",
 "new_user":"0",
 "device_token":""
 }]
```

Now I want to decode it and save the value of "id" in a variable.

```
$result=curl_exec($ch);
$books = json_decode($result, true);
echo ($books[0]['id']);
```

I tried the above code, but failed.

Comment: What is the error you have got ?

Comment: Thanks you for your response !BUt still having an issue.

Comment: @SivaKrishnaSamireddi check my answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `foreach()` loop for this.

```
foreach ($a[0] as $key => $value) {
echo $key."<br>".$value;
if($key == 'id'){
    $id = $value;
}
}

echo $id;
```

Also, if you just want to assign the value of `id` to another variable, you can just right

```
...
$no = $a[0]->id;
echo $no
...
```

instead of the foreach loop.

Comment: How can i assign the value of "id" to some variable ,say it $number?

Comment: kindly ask a different question for it. This will violate the stack protocols

Comment: So,Is it not possible to decode ?I am beginner,sorry if my question is wrong!

Comment: the json_decode($result) decodes the json object to an array(). so decoding is done.

Answer (score 1):

```
$books = json_decode($result, true);
foreach ($books as $book)
{
    //$book carries info of books;
    $id = $book['id'];
    ///... You can define other variables here
}
```

Comment: unexpected end of file in index.php on line 124.What it means?